# Pass a 'null' value to a MySQL database in node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to pass data from a Webscraper to a MySQL database. I have a lot of variables that need to be entered at a time into the database and below is a snippet of the code I'm using. (where the etc. is there are a bunch more variables.

```
con.query(INSERT INTO Paper_2 (referenceCodeSubject,referenceCode,subject, etc.) values ('"+referenceCodeSubject+"','"+referenceCode+"','"+subject+"', etc.))
```

The columns in the database have types INT, VARCHAR and CHAR.

My issue is that when I scrape not all of the variables will be assigned values and will remain as 'null' and I cannot pass this null as NULL to MySQL. It would also be quite complicated to sort the different cases for when to pass what due to the large amount of variables.

I'm hoping theres a simple way of doing this as the only solutions I've seen so far are omit the value in the query (which is hard because I would then need to decide which values to omit) or pass a string of "NULL" or just a value of 0. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Aren't you using parameterized queries? I hope you're not using string-concatenation, that's how you open yourself up to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: show your code?

Comment: hey there is no worry about SQL injection as I'm using puppeteer to scrape elements and store them locally in a MySQL database.

Comment: the codes really long like 500 lines and probably not very efficient (i'm a big noob) so i'm not sure its worth sharing. It gets the job done though, all thats missing is this final step.

Answer (score 1):

Better use the [built in escaping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values) feature to avoid sql injection attacks!

```js
conn.query(
  'INSERT INTO Paper_2 (referenceCodeSubject,referenceCode,subject) VALUES ?'
  [
    ['refCodeSubject1', 'refCode1', 'subject1'],
    ['refCodeSubject2', 'refCode2', null]
  ],
  (error, results, fields) => {
    ...
  }
)
```

Comment: as far as I'm concerned injection attacks are not an issue. Im using puppeteer to scrape data and store it into a local MySQL database that only I have access to (I'm really new to this so I might be wrong). Does the solution you suggest mean that I have to store the variables as an array?

Comment: Not necessarily, my solution suggests using built in escaping for providing values, if only for providing null value correctly. Like `conn.query('SELECT ?', [null], (error, result) => { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the case, that the bind values can sometime be a valid string and sometimes undefined, use an or operator in sqlValues to handle both cases with shorthand code:

```
let nameValue;

let sql="insert into user (name) values (?)"

let sqlValues[] = [nameValue || null ]
```

Answer (score 0):

nameValue ?? null not "||" because if nameValue = 0, nameValue || will be null

Comment: Please format the code in your answer correctly, and eventually give some more details, it's currently difficult to understand